# Is there a way to have QGIS treat numerical rasters as "date-rasters"?

Tags: qgis, date

I have a R-script outputting rasters where each raster cell contains dates (e.g. 2022-05-08).
I have considered various options to store this data in rasters and ended up using Unix Epoch data (i.e. the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1st, 1970). Since I know of no "date raster typer" ([see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/389993/is-there-a-raster-data-format-that-can-store-dates-instead-of-numeric-values)), this seems to be the most "standardized" way.

With this, the range of my dates are January 1st 2016 to let's say [2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) (so int32 suffices), resulting in values around:
1451606400 - 2145916800

This data is treated as classical numerical rasters. Is there a way to tell QGIS that this data represents a timestamp (and not a "classical" numerical value), e.g. when creating a symbology, or when creating an attribute of type date vs. a numerical attribute when sampling from the raster?